# bash print words on multiple lines in a single line

Tags: bash, printf, echo

I am writing a shell script for which I write a header that has 30 (growing) column names. Right now, I have a echo statement that works and looks like this

```
echo "Colum_Name1, Column_Name2,Column_Name30"
```

While this works the readability sucks for me. if i want to add a column, its a bit of a nightmare to look at the screen and understand whether it is already in there. of course, I search my way out. Is it possible to do something like this with echo or printf and get the CSV in one line?

```
echo " Column_Name1,
       Column_Name2,
       Column_Name30"
```

and get the output as

```
Column_Name1,Column_Name2,Column_Name30
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add backslash as the line continuation:

```
echo " Column_Name1,"\
       "Column_Name2,"\
       "Column_Name30"
```

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> The backslash character ‘\’ may be used to remove any special meaning
>   for the next character read and for line continuation.

Comment: @mklement0, nice catch! Thank you, will edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

Decouple the definition of the header and printing it, and use an array to store the column names.

```
headers=(
  Column_Name1
  Column_Name2
  Column_Name30
)

(IFS=","; printf '%s\n' "${headers[*]}")
```

The elements of the array are joined by the first character of `IFS` when `${headers[*]}` is expanded. The subshell is used so you don't have to worry about restoring the previous value of `IFS`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Convenience solution, using `paste`:

If you don't mind the (probably negligible) overhead of invoking an external utility (`paste`) to build your string, you can combine it with a (literal, in this case) [*here-doc*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument):

```
paste -s -d, - <<'EOF'
Column_Name1
Column_Name2
Column_Name30
EOF
```

yields

```
Column_Name1,Column_Name2,Column_Name30
```

The above acts like a *single-quoted* string, due to the opening delimiter, `'EOF'`, being *quoted*.
Omit the enclosing `'...'` to treat the string like a *double-quoted* string, i.e., with expansions being performed (allowing the inclusion of variable references, command substitutions, and arithmetic expansions).

If you take care to **use *actual* leading *tabs* (`\t`)** in your here-doc (multiple spaces do *not* work), you can even **introduce indentation**, by **prepending `-` to the opening delimiter**:

```
# !! Only works with actual *tabs* as the leading whitespace.
paste -s -d, - <<-'EOF'
    Column_Name1
    Column_Name2
    Column_Name30
EOF
```

---

#### More efficient solution, using *line continuation*:

**POSIX-compatible shells support line continuation even *inside* double-quoted strings, `"..."`** (but not inside *single*-quoted ones, `'...'`).

That means that **any `\<newline>` sequence inside a double-quoted string is *removed***:

```
echo "\
Column_Name1,\
Column_Name2,\
Column_Name3\
"
```

Given that **a here-document with an *unquoted* opening delimiter is treated like a double-quoted string**, you can do the following:

```
cat <<EOF
Column_Name1,\
Column_Name2,\
Column_Name30
EOF
```

Note:

- Using `<<-EOF` with to-be-stripped leading *tabs* (`\t`) for readability is *not* an option here, because the line continuations will *still*  include them.
- To take advantage of line continuation, it is invariably the *interpolating* (expanding) here-doc variety that must be used; therefore, you may need to `\`-escape `$` instances to ensure their *literal* use.

Both commands again yield the desired single-line string:

```
Column_Name1,Column_Name2,Column_Name30
```

Answer (score -3):

```
echo "foo bar" |  (IFS=" "; xargs -n 1 echo)
```

yields

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please note that OP wants to maintain a split (multiline) string in the script, but output it on one line.  The answer suggested does not address the OPs question.

Comment: Also notice that the idea in SO is to explain the logic of answers, to help others learn for the next time.
It is not a place just for "here is how to solve, run my code"